# How to solve system of equations in Do loop and replace the answer?

Tags: equation-solving, replacement

I want to solve equations and substitute one of the variable with the answer.
For example, here I have two variables (x, y) and two constants (a, b) ranging from 1~10, use FindRoot to solve them. I want to output only the x solution and replace it with the variable "x".

```
Do[sol = FindRoot[{a x + b y == 0, a x - b y == 4}, {x, 0}, {y, 0}], x = x /. sol[[1]], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}]
```

But there must be something wrong.
How can I solve it?
Thanks~

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to output only the x solution and replace it with the variable
> "x".

I am not sure what you mean by this. Do you want only the x solutions in list as numbers and assign this list to x? or something else?

```
Clear["Global`*"]
root[a_Integer, b_Integer, x_Symbol, y_Symbol] := 
 FindRoot[{a x + b y == 0, a x - b y == 4}, {x, 0}, {y, 0}]

data = Flatten[Table[root[a, b, x, y], {a, 1, 10}, {b, 1, 10}], 1];
data /. {x -> any1_, y -> any2_} :> x -> any1
```

The above gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you just want list of the x values assigned to x variable (btw, I think it is better to assign this to new variable name and not `x`. Something like `xSol`. So this below becomes `xSol = x /. data` but if you want to use `x` as variable then

```
x = x /. data
```

and now x variable is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And if you want only unique values in `x` you can do

```
x = Union[x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Other variations are possible.

Comment: Wow~thanks, this is helpful.